# PouchDB too much recursion - Stackoverflow on remote connection

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

EIDT: This Problem is an Angular2 Problem and should be resolved with the next zone.js update. For a temporary fix see: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/886 and Стефан Спасов Answer.

---

I'm trying to sync a client pouchDB with a server couchDB.

To access pouchDB from my Angular2 app I have written a javascript interface:

```
var db;
var remoteDb;

function LocalDb() {
  db = new PouchDB('test', {storage:'persistent'});
};

function RemoteDb(url) {
  remoteDb = new PouchDB(url);
};

function sync() {
  db.sync(remoteDb);
};

function addTest() {
  var test = {
    title: 'ABC',
    completed: false
  };

  db.post(test);
};
```

I removed all callbacks for readability. I installed pouchdb by running `npm install pouchdb`

I also added the pouchDB source by adding `<script src="../node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>` to index.html.

Because of the 404 Error i got by implementing it that way i copied the pouchDb dist folder into assets and implemented pouchDB that way `<script src="assets/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>`

All the javascript functions get called by buttons.

If i press the get localdb and the get remotedb button everythig works. At the moment i press the sync button I get a lot of `wrapFn@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3614:1` and a too much recursion error on firefox. Chrome tells me that the maximum call stack size exceeded.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit... Ok now I'm completely confused... i got it working by creating a single static html file and running it in the browser with EXCACTLY the same script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>RemoteCouch</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Hello World</h3>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="PATH/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var db = new PouchDB('new');

        db.post({
          name: 'David',
          age: 69
        });

        db.changes().on('change', function() {
          console.log('Ch-Ch-Changes');
        });

        db.replicate.to('http://10.20.20.37:5984/new');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hosted this file with the tapio/live-server and it works. This may be an Angular Problem, or i just did something wrong.

---

Just for one more try I made a new project, added pouchdb like described here https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find/issues/201 and did the same tests in pure typescript but as excpected the error is still there.

Comment: Ok I run some more tests and it seems like syncing is only a problem if I have data in the Db. If the db is empty it works without errors.
Also the syncing process works, it just comes with those messages. Data on both sides is perfectly in synch. My guess is that the browser kills the looping process as the stack size exceeds a certain value. I would still appreciate help...

Comment: Using the callback `db.sync(remoteDb).on('complete', function () {
    console.log('sync no error');
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('caught sync error');
  });` I found out that it is not an error that gets thrown by the sync function.

Comment: The error occurs on the put function aswell, nevertheless the put works... `remoteDb.put({
    _id: 'dave@gmail.com',
    name: 'David',
    age: 69
  });`

Comment: Just to make sure, my inserted data is probably not the problem bc I can do `remoteDb.put(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)));`

Comment: Update: I tried running the code in a **different module and imported** it into my app-component.html... still nothing. I am currently running the same code, without any problems in a **pure js** page, which is no longterm solution for me but shows that the error is either bc of me or ng2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and apparently there it is an issue with zone.js. Should be resolved in the next version. For the time being using v.0.8.16 solves the problem for me.

`"zone.js": "0.8.16"`

Here is a reference to the github issue: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/886

Comment: THANK YOU! The fix **"zone.js": "0.8.16"** didn't work for me but the github page was perfect. Fixed the problem by downloading the zip in the link and extracting it in zone.js. I will update my post soon.